# Angular CLI dynamic routing

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a website in such a way that the routing gets updated automatically from information on the server.  So for example say I have several categories that have subcategories under it.  The server would return this info and then routing would be created for it.

I currently accomplish this like so.

```
public mapDynamicRoutes(categories: any) {

for (let category = 0; category < categories.length; category++) {
  if (categories[category].SubCategories !== undefined) {
    for (let subCategory = 0; subCategory < categories[category].SubCategories.length; subCategory++) {
      this.router.config.push(
        {
          path: categories[category].Name
          + '/' + categories[category].SubCategories[subCategory].Name,
          component: NavigatorComponent
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

}

the categories parameter comes from the server.  This can change as new categories are added.  So in my app.module.ts I only have a route for the home page, and the rest of the routes get added on my nav bar component.  This all works correctly.  However, since the routes are reloaded every time, trying to browser directly to localhost:4200/category/subcategory fails saying the route doesn't exist.  In my app.module.ts I have a routes variable with the home route and I call RouterModule.forRoot(routes) with that variable.  Then inside of the constructor I fill in the rest of the routes.  Somehow though navigating directly to a route doesn't function correctly.  I'm guessing the navigation functionality hits routes before the other routes have been loaded?  Navigating normally through my nav bar works correctly.  Any ideas would be appreciated.